# Framework for developing all the mobile applications?

Tags: mobile, internationalization

i need to create an application which should be run in all mobile platforms.. i searched in net and I get rhomobile.. But the thing is dat i need to develop my application in malayalam text. so any on please help me to find a suilatable framework for developing my application

Comment: What do you mean by ALL mobile platforms? iOS, Android and WP7? Blackberry? Windows Mobile? Symbian? There are many more...

Comment: @mzabsky:yes on all mobile platforms

Comment: Download [Worklight](http://www.worklight.com/) - Using WL you can build cross-platform apps in a mater of second!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using Java and J2ME Polish (http://www.j2mepolish.org).it's able to port to Symbian, BlackBerry and Android on the fly. iOS and WP7 can be ported too (but not on the fly).

Answer (score 0):

How about [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)? You can code your app in Javascript (useful if you have web development skills) and compile to IPhone or Android.

Answer (score 0):

check http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/ ,IBM Worklight provides an open, comprehensive and advanced mobile application platform for smartphones and tablets, helping organizations of all sizes .

Can develop same app for Iphone,Android, blackberry,just needs to chand the environment for three wich is provided with the worklight tool.